# tkinter : how do I dynamically change number of columns in my tree view

Tags: python, tkinter, data-manipulation

This is more of a python data manipulation question than tkinter (imo). I have added my codes below, which works fine. At the moment I am defining 12 columns and the view is populated by the df

```
root = Tk()
root.minsize(width=600, height=700)
#root.resizable(width=0, height=0)

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, selectmode='browse',height='10')
tree.place(x=330, y=45)

vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
vsb.place(x=320, y=45, height=200 + 180)

tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

#frm = Frame(root)
#frm.pack(padx=0, pady=10, anchor='nw')
#frm.pack(side=tk.LEFT,padx=0,pady=10)
#frm.pack(padx=0,pady=10)

tree["columns"] = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
tree['show'] = 'headings'
tree['height'] = '20'

tree.column(1, width=150, anchor='c')
tree.heading(1, text="Account")

for i in range(2,13):
    tree.column(i, width=100, anchor='c')
    tree.heading(i, text="Type")

for i in df:
    tree.insert('','end',values=i)

root.title('New Data')
root.geometry('650x500')
#root.resizable(False,False)
root.mainloop()
```

As I said the code works fine, but question is using python how can I change the below code so that it dynamically changes column count according to number of columns in my df

```
tree["columns"] = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
```

i.e. if there are only 3 columns the code is

```
tree["columns"] = (1,2,3)
```

Comment: Just do `tree["columns"] = df.columns.tolist()`?

Comment: no that won't work, if my df had 3 columns 'a','b' and 'c' then you code will give me as an output ['a','b','c'],  while what I want is (1,2,3). likewise if there were 4 columns 'a','b','c' and 'd' then what I want is (1,2,3,4).

Comment: then use `list(range(1, len(df.columns)))`.

Comment: ah why did I not think of that before! realised I could use [1,2,3] instead of (1,2,3...) in my codes i.e. use square brackets. In that case your code works perfectly! thanks again.